# checkField() doesn't check behat mink

Tags: php, behat, mink

I'm trying to use the `checkField()` for the first time, it's found the checkbox but doesn't check it.

The html:

```
<label>
    <input class="sr-only" value="on" type="checkbox">
    <span>I want an open return</span>
<label>
```

Look at the code:

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->checkField("I want an open return");
```

I also try it:

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only")->check();
```

Boths doesn't return any error but I can see the checkbox isn't check when I run the test.

The follow code return bool(false) as expected:

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only")->isChecked();
```

Comment: Make sure the element found is input checkbox. Add the html for this element if possible.

Comment: I put more info now :)

Comment: Add a breakpoint/sleep after you check the checkbox and see if it was checked or not.

Comment: When I run the test I can see the checkbox isn't check.

Answer (score 0):

`checkField()` might not work, because this relies on the `value` attribute of the element, if is `true/false` and you have `on/off` which will fail in evaluating the status of the checkbox, same thing for `check()`.

As an alternative to `check` you can find the element and `click()`:

```
find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only")->click();
```

Checking if is checked with `isChecked()` will fail for the same reason.

You might need to do a custom validation, for example get the value of the `value` attribute and check it if is `on` or `off` and throw exception or return status as needed.

Things to keep in mind:
 - inspect the page and check if selector is ok
 - make sure the selector finds only one element, or the first element found in the list is the one you need
 - make sure you wait for the element if needed
 - use page objects
 - the class that contains this click/check should extend the Page object and the line should look like this:

```
$this->find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only")->click();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using behat version 3.2.1

But when I tried to use 
$this->find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only")->check(); 

I saw a Fatal error: Call to undefined method WidgetContext::find() (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)

Comment: Yes, depending of what that class is extending, then keep it as it is. Have you checked if the selectors finds one or more elements in the page?

Comment: This code:

`var_dump($this->getSession()->getPage()->find("css", "input[type=checkbox].sr-only"));`

Returns it: [https://codeshare.io/2jklK5]

I don't understand the return.

Comment: Link not working, says Codeshare is over capacity. try with https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `isChecked()` not fail but the `click()` doesn't works :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's works, after change "input" to "label" using the follow code line:

> $this->getSession()->getPage()->findAll("css", ".div-name
>   .second-div-name label")[0]->click();

My checkbox input was inside two divs, because that I have this two divs names above.

=)